# Configure Axios as reusable module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to create a axios config file where I can create several apis with different configurations, e.g. `http.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

const backendApi =  axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL + "api/",
});

const anotherApi =  axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com",
});

export default {
  backendApi,
  anotherApi
};
```

Now I want to use the `backendApi`, e.g. in my `actions.js`:

```
import backendApi from "@/http"

const userRegister = (context, user) => {

  backendApi
    .post("users/register", user)
    .then((resp) => {
      //
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //
    })
}

export default {
  userRegister
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: *http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.default.post is not a function"

Comment: Could you try with `export default backendApi;` ?

Comment: @panepeter yes, that works. But what if I have more than one api configured? (see updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using exports the way you intend to.

What you want is `named` exports instead of a `default` one.

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const backendApi =  axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL + "api/",
});

export const anotherApi =  axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com",
});
```

```js
import { backendApi } from "@/http"

export const userRegister = (context, user) => {
  backendApi
    .post("users/register", user)
    .then((resp) => {
      //
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //
    })
}
```